# Is it possible to to solve algebraically: $e^z=z$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

While solving $e^z=z$, I realise there is no real solution and want to find a complex solution, if any.

I searched around the internet only to find functions describing approximations that might be sufficiently close, but I can't find a way to know the exact answer.

My question is :

DERIVE all solutions to $e^z=z$ (and prove if there are none)   :-)

I'm NOT interested in the answer, I am interested in the solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

HINT: defining $$f(x)=e^{x}-x$$ and then we have $$f'(x)=e^{x}-1$$ and $$f''(x)=e^{x}>0$$
and the solution is given by $$x=-{\rm W} \left(-1\right)$$ with the LambertW-function.
and the complex solution is given by $$x\approx  0.3181315052- 1.337235701\,i$$

Comment: @ajotatxe : yes, it is not an ordered field.

Comment: In general, $x=-W_k(-1)$, where $W_k(z)$ is the $k$-th branch of the Lambert function.